# How to load a bitmap segmentation using cornerstone segmentation and brush tool?

Tags: cornerstonejs

I'm trying to load a 2d bitmap that involves some segmentation information regarding a study and would like to use the available tools to do so. While going through documents I can't find any discrete example to achieve this. Anyone has any idea of doing it with cornerstoneTools.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [cornerstoneTools >= 4.0](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneTools/releases/tag/v4.0.1) version for that. As you can see in this [issue](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneTools/issues/1061), **Labelmap Renderer** is already implemented from here. Maybe, you should also look at the [`cornerstoneWebImageLoader`](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneWebImageLoader) repository.

Then, you can do as follows:

```js
cornerstone.loadImage(imageId).then(image => {
cornerstone.displayImage(element, image);

cornerstoneTools.mouseInput.enable(element);
cornerstoneTools.mouseWheelInput.enable(element);
...
}).then(() => {
    let pixelData = new Uint8ClampedArray(width * height * channel);
    for (let i = 128; i < 256; i++) {
        for (let j = 256; j < 384; j++) {
            pixelData[i*width + j] = 1;
        }
    }
    ...
    cornerstone.updateImage(element);
});
```